# Version of gradle bundled with intellijidea is unsupported

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I tried to set up libgdx with Idea, but i have stumbled upon a problem, it says that the version of gradle that was BUNDLED WITH THE IDE, is unsupported. I have no more information.

Comment: No information? No picture? No exception? Why not download gradle separately and sepcify it in Preferences. What version of intellij is this?

Comment: i got it to work with eclipse, all is good